# How do I wait for the iteration before moving on the next one?

Tags: python, loops, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to scrape a webpage using selenium in python and it has a 'Load more' button at the bottom of it, now I need to click the button a total of 114 times which is stored inside of a variable 'count_all'

```
for i in tqdm(range(count_all)):
    try:
        css_selector = 'load-more-trigger'
        driver.find_element(By.ID, css_selector).click()
    except:
        pass
```

The issue I am running into, is this only clicks the 'Load more' about two times before the loop is done iterating, I want it to wait every iteration to click the button, move on to the next iteration and so on.

How can I achieve this ? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explicit waits in your code as following :

```
for i in tqdm(range(count_all)):
    try:
        css_selector = 'load-more-trigger'
        load_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, css_selector)))
        load_more_button.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(load_more_button))
    except:
        pass
```

please update the imports accordingly in your test file like below

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi Thankyou for your answer, I wish to ask you two things: the first is that this way takes quite a bit of time I see, about 19 minutes since the wait is quite long, is there a way to make it quicker ? the second thing I want to ask you is can you explain what the code does ? you have added two different waits and I don't quite understand what they do, apologies since I am not particularly great at logic.

Comment: While automating anything we need to make sure that the element with which we are going to work on, must be available on the page for that we have to make use of explicit wait that is WebDriverWait. The logic here what is applied is EC (Expect Conditions) which refers to wait for an element to appear until some condition satisfied. In this case we are asking the driver to wait the presence of element for some longer time.

Comment: If you want to make the time less and throw an exception after some time you can use timeouts like  : load_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector)))

Comment: The second one - The WebDriverWait instance waits for the element to become stale, which means that it is no longer attached to the DOM of the web page. Staleness often occurs when the element is removed or replaced by dynamic content updates.